# Oracle "new or old reference not allowed in table level trigger"

Tags: oracle, trigger, plsql

I have this table

```
CREATE table Pharmacists (
PhFname varchar2(10),
PhLname varchar2(10),
Salary number(7),
Nationality varchar2(10),
Shift_Start varchar2(2),
Shift_End varchar2(2),
PhID number(7) primary key,
Super_ID number(7) ,
bdate date,
constraint super_fk foreign key (Super_ID) references Pharmacists (PhID) on delete cascade);
```

I tried to create this trigger

```
create or replace trigger updShE
after update of Shift_Start on Pharmacists
begin
update Pharmacists
set Shift_End=to_number(:new.Shift_Start, '99') +8 
where PhID = :New.PhID ;
end;
```

but this error appears

> new or old reference not allowed in table level trigger

Comment: Unrelated, but: I would store `shift_start` and `shift_end` (which seems to be a time of day information) as a number to make calculations easier. E.g. minutes since midnight or just "hours" if you don't need minutes. Storing numbers in `varchar` columns is usually a bad idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a row before level trigger for that.

And you don't need an update, just assign the new value:

```
create or replace trigger updshe
  BEFORE update of Shift_Start on Pharmacists
  FOR EACH ROW
begin
  :new.shift_end := to_number(:new.Shift_Start, '99') + 8;
end;
/
```

Comment: error can't change new values for this trigger type

Comment: @Randalrand: ah sorry, I overlooked that you are using an `after` trigger. You obviously need a BEFORE trigger for that

Comment: thank you it's working now but why before not after? why should we not use update?